# Why is Salesforce's translation system so bad?

Tags: translation, translation-workbench, localization

For almost two decades I've worked with gettext PO files, which is just a pleasure to work with. It solves a lot of problems, is very DRY, and is super translator-friendly. And then we have the translation workbench - it feels archaic and outdated and has already felt like this when I started working with Salesforce 12+ years ago. So why is it that Salesforce doesn't have any good i18n built in?

One of my personal guesses is that it has something to do with how you can access locale information - because you just cannot. It is 100% tied to the user's locale and causes big problems whenever you need to format something outside of the user's locale. You need to re-invent the wheel for that if you need it.

Second - Salesforce is working with languages that you can select, not locales (and least on the outside). This might seem like a minor difference but it's a mistake often made if you start your i18n journey when you just make translations for a specific language and forget about the region it is being used in. This also means that there's no way to cater to the e.g. whole DACH region with correct locales for each of the German-speaking countries. I can only have one German translation for all of them.

My third guess - back in the day they rolled out this simple system and just stick with it. A topic like i18n is super hard - even for a tech giant like Salesforce. And it's even harder to modernize. Just think about how supposedly simple things were handled over the years (switch statement anyone?) - now transfer that turtle-fixing speed over to a more complicated topic.

My final guess - it's just not fancy enough. Cool features like flows get all the attention while features that would make your application more robust, easier to use, and easier to develop are just not a priority. And it applies only to companies that MUST cater to different languages anyway.

But surely, as always - there might be some history to it. And surely I'm dead wrong about certain aspects if not all. I would really appreciate it if somebody could shine some light on this.